# AS3 (or AS2) - Global Variables as Local inside Functions

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm assuming there's something easy i'm overlooking here.
But basically, What i'm trying to do is just simply..  I guess code would be a better explanation, here it goes:

```
tobj = (an Array containing objects.)

for(i = 0; i < tobj.length; i++) {
   tobj[i].func = function() {
       trace(i);
   }
}
```

Basically, i understand what happens here.. i as the global variable changes, so if i execute that function it'll retrieve the last value of i regardless of what it was when it was assigned. Basically I'm trying to figure out here is what approach to use to convert i as a global, into a local, so that when i execute the function on the object, it'll output the variable as it was assigned.

Hope it's understandable and straight forward. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you add parenthesis after the closing bracket of your function declaration, it will run the function:

```
var tobj = [new Object(),new Object(), new Object()];

for(var i = 0; i < tobj.length; i++) {
     tobj[i].func = function() {
     trace(i);
}() // < ------
```

This would trace: "0", "1", "2"

Comment: This works as well and is definitely an easier approach than my own answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution... There might be another way, but this is what worked for me. Just took walking away from it for a few minutes.

```
tobj = (an Array containing objects.)

for(i = 0; i < tobj.length; i++) {
   tobj[i].func = function() {
       assigner(i);
   }
}

function assigner(var) {
   trace(var);
}
```